# Why a certain shortcode parameter doesn't work in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

The following is my shortcode function, it will show a member infomation

```
/*[member][/member]*/
add_shortcode('member', 'van_member_shortcode');
function van_member_shortcode( $atts, $content = "" ) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'avatar'=>get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default_avatar.jpg',
        'name' => '',
        'job' => '',
        'facebook' => '',
        'twitter' => '',
        'dribbble'=> '',
        'flickr' => '',
        'googlePlus' => ''
   ), $atts));      

   $str='<div class="member">';
   $str.='<div class="avatar">';
   $str.='<div class="overlay">';
   $str.='<div class="social">';
   if($facebook<>''){
   $str.='<a href="'.esc_attr($facebook).'" class="facebook"></a>';
   }
   if($twitter<>''){
   $str.='<a href="'.esc_attr($twitter).'" class="twitter"></a>';
   }
   if($dribbble<>'') {
   $str.='<a href="'.esc_attr($dribbble).'" class="dribbble"></a>';
   }
   if($flickr<>'') {
   $str.='<a href="'.esc_attr($flickr).'" class="flickr"></a>';
   }
   if($googlePlus<>''){
   $str.='<a href="'.esc_attr($googlePlus).'" class="gplus"></a>';
   }
   $str.='</div>';
   $str.='</div>';
   if($avatar==''){
   $str.='<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default_avatar.jpg" />';
   }else{
   $str.='<img src="'.esc_attr($avatar).'" />';
   }
   $str.='</div><hgroup>';
   $str.='<h2>'.esc_attr($name).'</h2>';
   $str.='<span>'.esc_attr($job).'</span>';
   $str.='</hgroup><p class="intro">'.van_shortcode($content).'</p>';
   $str.='</div>';
   return $str;
}
```

Usage:

```
[member name="Ane" job="Graphic designer" avatar="" facebook="http://www.facebook.com" twitter="http://www.twitter.com" dribbble="http://www.dribbble.com" flickr="http://www.flickr.com" googlePlus="http://plus.google.com"]
Aenean malesuada diam ac urna pulvinar posuere fringilla magna congue. Mauris a eros felis.
[/member]
```

But when I added googlePlus="http://plus.google.com", the google plus icon doesn't shown, I don't know why, did I miss anything?

Comment: I don't see where, in the code, you refer to a Google Plus icon?

Comment: did you check your CSS ? is the icon there with the right class name ?

Comment: The CSS is right, I checked the HTML code, the google icon link wasn't generated.

Comment: I refer to g+ icon as this line : if($googlePlus<>''){
   $str.='<a href="'.esc_attr($googlePlus).'" class="gplus"></a>';
   }